# correct usage of multiprocessing for image download

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote the following function and tested it out in python shell and the images were downloaded successfully, however, when I ran it in a script no images were downloaded.

```
import os
import requests
from time import time
import uuid
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
main_file_name = 'test1.csv'

my_set = set()
with open(main_file_name, 'r') as f:  #read image urls 
    for row in f:
        my_set.add(row.split(',')[2].strip())

def get_url(entry):
    path = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpg"
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        r = requests.get(entry, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r:
                    f.write(chunk)

start = time()
results = ThreadPool(8).imap_unordered(get_url, my_set)
print(f"Elapsed Time: {time() - start}")
```

I double-checked and it works in shell, is there anything I am missing from the script

Comment: Try putting moving the `get_url()` definition to the top after the imports and then put everything left, indented, within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. For an explanation of why the if `__name__` == '`__main__`' part is necessary, see the "Safe importing of main module" section of the multiprocessing [Processing Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

Comment: @martineau it didn't fix, anyway I am not getting an error the `print` statement is executed but without any image downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"results" is of class `multiprocessing.pool.IMapUnorderedIterator`, a good way to make sure the URLs are downloaded is to actually loop on `results`

```
start = time()
results = ThreadPool(8).imap_unordered(fetch_url, my_set)
for _ in results:
    pass
print(f"Elapsed Time: {time() - start}")
```

Another method which will also do the trick is to make sure the main thread completes before exiting from the script is to use `time.sleep`

```
from time import sleep
start = time()
results = ThreadPool(8).imap_unordered(fetch_url, my_set)
sleep(10)  # make sure this amount is enough to finish downloading
print(f"Elapsed Time: {time() - start}")
```

The reason your script doesn't work is that you immediately end the script after your initiation of `results`.The reason `python3 -i test.py` (or simply copy-paste your code in the shell) works is because the script was not killed (main thread lives) so the images had the time to be downloaded.

Comment: Good answer. One thing I'd recommend changing though: don't use `sleep` like this. The right way to wait for threads to exit is to call `join`: `pool=ThreadPool(8); results=pool.imap(fetch_url, my_set); pool.close(); pool.join()`. The only downside here is that `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.join` doesn't accept a timeout.